# PHP cURL and response code 302

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to make a POST sending a page with the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.olx.es/posting_success.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("itemid" => $json['id'], "sh" => $json['sh']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And in doing so I returned a server error saying "Invalid Request".

I've noticed that if I do the request manually by telnet, the first time I returned a 302, despite the fact that I've put to follow him, not work, and maybe it's this.

With wireshark obtained what the customer actually sent, what am I doing wrong?

```
**Hypertext Transfer Protocol:**
POST /posting_success.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.olx.es
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.olx.es
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.olx.es/posting.php?categ_id=322
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

**Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded:**
itemid=501347053&sh=b9302ed20769ae3717f896a33a369aa2
```

Sorry for my english..

Comment: can you share page of original form?

Comment: Maybe it's not because of this, but if you use an array as a value for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, then you should use a different `Content-type`, from the PHP doc: *If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.*

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make custom request, sent such headers or use CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT.
Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.olx.es/posting_success.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( array("itemid" => $json['id'], "sh" => $json['sh']) ));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

It Seems You have Problem in POST request. please Try

```
$fields=array('itemid' => $json['id'], 'sh' =>urlencode ($json['sh']));
```

Format Your Fields

```
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
```

Then Use in Curl OPt

```
    curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to do what you ask, and there is no way, I returned the following

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;77db6ad4&#46;1365972392&#46;33761686
</BODY>
</HTML>

** vardump **
[fields] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 501855068
            [sh] => fb9c6e45c0a2dbd3a497029425f2e4b6
        )

Comment: I looked my request with wireshark and now I returns error 411 Length Required

Comment: there's something you still missing. Try Setting the `Content-length` in header. Usually it represent the fault in responding server

Comment: Hello, I've added the Content-length so: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Length: ".strlen($fields_string), "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); but now in the curl call, the server seems unresponsive, not even skip the php timeout or anything..

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, this form is not multipart/form-data, and then you will to create a query string to post. See the manpage http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. you give then an array. The the header will be set a multipart/form-data. And this is the invalid request.

**THE SOLUTION IS**

The string is simple to build "&itemid=".json['id']."&sh=".json['sh'];
put this in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

saludos (bye) and sorry for my english...